# Issue with Scikit Learn Package for SVR Regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, svm, libsvm

I am trying to fit a SVM regression model using Scikit Learn Package but it is not working like I am expecting.

Could you please help me to find the error? The code that I  would like to use is:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import numpy as np


X = []
x = np.arange(0, 20)
y = [3, 4, 8, 4, 6, 9, 8, 12, 15, 26, 35, 40, 45, 54, 49, 59, 60, 62, 63, 68]
X.append(x)

clf = SVR(verbose=1)
clf.fit(np.transpose(X), y)

print("Expecting Result:")
print(y)
print("Predicted Result:")
print(clf.predict(np.transpose(X)))
```

The Output that I have is:

```
[LibSVM]*
optimization finished, #iter = 10
obj = -421.488272, rho = -30.500000
nSV = 20, nBSV = 20
Expecting Result:
[3, 4, 8, 4, 6, 9, 8, 12, 15, 26, 35, 40, 45, 54, 49, 59, 60, 62, 63, 68]
Predicted Result:
[ 29.1136814   28.74580196  28.72748632  28.72736291  28.7273628
  28.7273628   28.72736302  28.72760984  28.76424112  29.5         31.5
  32.23575888  32.27239016  32.27263698  32.2726372   32.2726372
  32.27263709  32.27251368  32.25419804  31.8863186 ]
```

We can see that the predicted results are very far from the training data. 
How can I improve the fitting?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an edge case where RBF (default for SVM on scikit-learn) kernels don't work very well.

Change the SVR line to this:
`clf = SVR(verbose=1, kernel='linear')` and you will see much more reasonable results.

`[LibSVM]Expecting Result:
[3, 4, 8, 4, 6, 9, 8, 12, 15, 26, 35, 40, 45, 54, 49, 59, 60, 62, 63, 68]
Predicted Result:
[ -6.9  -2.9   1.1   5.1   9.1  13.1  17.1  21.1  25.1  29.1  33.1  37.1
  41.1  45.1  49.1  53.1  57.1  61.1  65.1  69.1]`

I understand that you are just trying to get a feel for how SVM's work. Take a look at [this](https://charlesmartin14.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/kernels_part_1/) blog post for how RBF kernels work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tested and it works. I will be more vigilant on the kernel choice.